# How to add to an already allocated char?

Tags: c++, c

This is a really simple question.

I have a structure with a char buffer[250].

```
struct testStruct{
   char buffer[250];
};
```

How do I add, let's say-- "test characters" to that buffer?

I can't really do a simple assignment like newStruct.buffer = "test characters";

Comment: Why not look up string - i.e. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: What language are you using - C or C++? These are two different languages, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newStruct.buffer = "test characters";` puts the constant value of `"test characters"` to the pointer of the array `buffer`. Obviously you're new to C and C++ programming, you should read on that a little bit more please, try [here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/) and [here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/).

Comment: `newStruct.buffer` is an array, not a pointer. That assignment is illegal.

Comment: Try it. The name of an array is **not** a pointer to its first element. In most contexts it **decays** into a pointer to its first element. Not here: `buffer` is an array of 250 `char`, not a pointer to `char`, and you cannot assign another array to it.

Comment: What do you mean by _decay_ ?

Comment: "turns into". Try it.

Comment: I just tried `int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}; printf("%d",*x);` and it worked(printed _1_). Do you have an example where it might not work that way?

Comment: That's **initialization**, not **assignment**. Try the code that you posted.

Comment: aaa now I get your point, you're right about the **assignment** issue,  the VS2012 C++ compiler gives an error and says it cannot compile `const char[]` to `int[]`.

Comment: Note that the error message is about `int[]`, i.e., an array. Now try `strcpy` to a `const char buffer[250];` and you'll probably get an error message about `const char*`, not `const char[]`, because of the decay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function **`sprintf` or `snprintf` or `strcpy` or `strncpy`**

so something like this:

```
sprintf(newStruct.buffer,"%s","test characters"); // doesnt protect against buffer overflow

snprintf(newStruct.buffer,250,"%s","test characters"); // guards against overflows

strcpy(newStruct.buffer,"test characters"); // as suggested in another answer also doesnt guard against overflows

strncpy(newStruct.buffer,"test characters",250);// guards against overflows
```

( instead of explicitly mentioning size 250 in `snprintf` and `strncpy` , you can use the `sizeof` function/instruction instead )

---

This will put "test characters" into the buffer array with a `\0` character at the end ...

You can append more strings to it using `strcat` function if needed later.

here is the `man` page for sprintf:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

Comment: strcpy gives you a chance of overflow

Comment: sprintf can also overflow

Comment: Just my 2 cents - nice article related to the problem here http://randomascii.wordpress.com/?s=strncpy

Comment: @Artur strcpy_safe is a neat way to hide hideous \0 checks in a function

Comment: `strncpy` and `snprintf` quietly replace buffer overruns with data corruption. If your design doesn't guarantee that the target buffer is large enough, **you have to check**.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(newStruct.buffer, "test characters");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have an array of `char`, you can use `strcpy`. This function will copy each character until the end of the string ('\0' is also copied). You can also use `strncpy` for security matters.

```
#include <string.h>

char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
```

Remember that the order of the arguments is in fact the same as an affectation: `dest = src`.

You can also use `sprintf` for more advanced stuff. It's similar to `printf` but writes in the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

However, if you don't have an already allocated string, have a look to `strdup` when the source string could possibly be freed.

Back to your case, you can't write something like that: `newStruct.buffer = "test characters";` because it would try to change the address of `newStruct.buffer` to point somewhere else. That would only be possible with a pointer (`char*`) but not with an array.

```
strcpy(newStruct.buffer, "test characters");
```

or

```
strncpy(newStruct.buffer, "test characters", sizeof(newStruct.buffer));
```

Comment: If you pass it a string that's too long, `strncpy` will corrupt your data. It is not a substitute for careful design and checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to append a string saying to add then you should use standard C functions either strcat or strncat provided that the last actual character in buffer is the terminating zero. 
If you want to copy a string into buffer starting from the first character of buffer you should use standard C function either strcpy or strncpy.
For example if you are sure that the length of the string is less than 250 then you can write simply

```
std::strcpy( buffer, "test characters" );
```

If You do not know the size of the string you are going to copy then you can use strncpy

```
std::strncpy( buffer, SomeString, 250 );
buffer[249] = '\0';
```

In this case it is possible that the copy will be truncated.

If buffer already contains some string and you are going to append a new one then again your selection deoends on whether you are sure that the new string will fit in buffer,

If you are sure then you can write

```
strcat( buffer, "test characters" );
```

If you are not sure you can write

```
size_t n = 250 - std::strlen( buffer );

strcat( buffer, SomeString, n );
buffer[249] = '\0';
```